# Permissions access

Tags: google-drive-api

The new version 2 API introduce methods to access permissions. Apps can create, delete, modify and read one permission but why the get method does't return the value property which limits what apps can do with permissions ? The JavaScript embeddable sharing component is a solution for some use cases but not for all.

Answer (score 0):

The value property is omitted in order to preserve privacy. A user that can read the permissions on a file should not be able to see the email addresses of all the other users with permissions.

You should use the permission id, which can be found with the [about](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) method as the [about resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource), and is:

```
The current user's ID as visible in the permissions collection.
```

Comment: OK for the privacy argument for a user other than owner but what about this file's owner ?