# Where can I see shared users for a file using Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to use Google Drive API to monitor documents within our organization and make sure that nobody is sharing files improperly.  In order to do so, I need to be able to see who (or what groups) currently have access to a document in Drive.  I thought that the Drive API would be perfect for this, but when I look up a file in the API the info is totally unhelpful.

Each file has a list of permissions, but when I request this list it doesn't say WHO each permission applies to.  They say the role (i.e. "reader", "owner", etc) and the type (i.e. "user", "group", etc), but the email_address field is always blank.  Even when I'm the owner of the file, or the permission applies to me.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there any way that I can see who the file permissions apply to?  Or am I out of luck?

Here is a condensed version of the PHP code that I'm using:

```
/* getClient creates and returns a Google_Client */
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

/* I use the service to look at my files and get a file id */
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 20,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    $permissions = $service->permissions->listPermissions($file->getId());
    var_dump($permissions);
}
```

P.S. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240253/permissions-access) suggests that email addresses are left out for privacy reasons (and also seems to imply that they're *never* visible?)  But it's also talking about V2 of the API and so I don't know if it applies.  Also I don't understand why it would hide the emails addresses for privacy reasons when I can clearly see them while using Google Drive in browser.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Try making your request using fields=* parameter.   Without seeing your code I cant tell you how to do that.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, I totally forgot the fields parameter.  Included it and now it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) pointed out, I just needed to specify my fields in the request.  All I did was change:

```
$permissions = $service->permissions->listPermissions($file->getId());
```

into:

```
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 20,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, permissions(id, emailAddress, role, type)'
);
$permissions = $service->permissions->listPermissions($file->getId(), $optParams);
```

and now I can see the email addresses as expected.

Comment: Drive v3 has a drawback (IMO) that it doesnt return all the fields by default you need to request them yourself.   [fields parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)